# Export JupyterLab 3.* with %matplotlib widgets to html

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab, matplotlib-widget

I'm running into an issue with exporting my notebooks from Jupyter Lab. I work with 3D figures and want to export the entire notebook as HTML with images in the current state. I was able to do so in Jupyter Notebook with the `%matplotlib notebook` command. However, when using the export function in Jupyter Lab after calling `%matplotlib widget`, the output becomes something like:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this issue? Or a way to use `%matplotlib notebook` in Jupyter Lab?

#### Versions

```
python 3.7.9 
ipympl version: 0.6.3
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.21.0
ipykernel        : 5.5.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.11
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.2
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```